# Text + tabular data for classification

Tags: classification, nlp, text-classification

I have a dataset of "mixed" types e.g

```
text |  date  | amount  |  supplier
-----+--------+---------+------------
```

where `text` is rather short sentences (text from banktransactions), `date` is when the transaction occured,`amount` the amount of the transaction and `supplier` being where they have purchased it from e.g "Wallmart".

I want to predict the `supplier`.

Using only the `text` (Tf-IDF + KNN) I can achieve a (precison,recall) = (0.94,0.4) (overall), but for some `suppliers` I can see that the `amount` could help differentiate even more since some suppliers have almost identical text, but the amount differes greatly. My issue is though that I find it difficult to add the `amount` as a feature.

What I have tried is:

1. Using the `supplier` predictions, based on text, aswell with the `amount` as a feature in a LightGBM model. Overall that didn't do anything good
2. Using the `amount` as an interactive term between the probability predicitons from a Logistic Regression regression, in a new Logistic Regression (didn't do very much overall aswell)

I can find a lot (!) of text regarding text-classification but I struggle to find anything about text+tabular classification. Any ideas of how to tackle such problems?